# ¿Cómo evitar que Google Analytics registre mi actividad en mi sitio web?

Tags: api, google-api, google-analytics

Deseo impedir que Google Analytics registre la actividad que tengo en mi proprio sitio web para evitar contaminar los datos que recoge, para ello quisiera poner un filtro que excluya la dirección IP de mi router de manera que todos mis dispositivos sean excluidos aunque sé que no es la mejor opción porque no registraría los datos de otros que compartan mi mismo IP en internet, pero el sistema que utiliza las cookies no es factible en mi caso. Otras opciones que no incluyan las cookies son bienvenidas.

He notado que hay un filtro que Google Analytics nos da por defecto con este objetivo pero no se como configurarlo, es el que se ve en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me parece poco intuitivo, tras hacer pruebas y leer la documentación no he logrado hallar el modo de hacerlo funcionar. Sigue registrando la actividad de mis dispositivos.

Comment: En los filtros de la Vista en cuestión, puedes añadir uno personalizado cuyo campo sea Dirección IP y aplicar ahí el patron válido para tu navegacion o el de tu oficina

Comment: Agradecería un ejemplo más visual. Tampoco entendí a que se refiere con “patrón válido de navegación”

Comment: Una expresión regular que contemple las IP's a excluir

Comment: Eso ya lo he intentado y no funciona. Como puedes ver en la imagen hay otros campos y no sé como van configurados. Además existe un tipo de filtro llamado trafico interno y me gustaría saber como configurarlo.

Comment: Para crear el filtro actual que aparece en la imagen seguiste [estos pasos](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034840?hl=es)?

Comment: Si, lo había hecho justo así. En ese link se explica como filtrar los datos al interno de una vista y me funcionó, solo que yo estaba intentando filtrar los datos de toda la propiedad. ¿Es posible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma más sencilla es usar la extensión de Chrome [**Block Yourself from Analytics**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-yourself-from-analy/fadgflmigmogfionelcpalhohefbnehm)

¿Cómo utilizar [**Block Yourself from Analytics**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-yourself-from-analy/fadgflmigmogfionelcpalhohefbnehm)?

Abrir la configuración de la extensión, vaya a la lista de sitios web y agregue todos sus sitios web a la lista.
Puedes usar `example.com` o `www.example.com` para la concordancia exacta o usar comodines como `* example.com` para hacer coincidir `example.com` con todos sus subdominios. Tomar en cuenta que si colocas un punto entre wildchar (*) y nombre de dominio, solo coincidirá con subdominios y no con su nombre de dominio simple.

La extensión está disponible para Chrome, Edge, Firefox y Opera.

---

La otra forma es mediante [**Google Analytics**](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=es), realizando un filtro.

1. Empieza por [**crear un nuevo filtro para su vista o cuenta**](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823).
2. Introduce un nombre para tu filtro en el campo Nombre del filtro.
3. Deja Predefinido seleccionado como Tipo de filtro.
4. Selecciona `Exclude` en el menú desplegable Seleccionar tipo de filtro.
5. Selecciona el tráfico de las direcciones IP del menú desplegable Seleccionar origen o destino.
6. Selecciona que sean iguales a en el menú desplegable Seleccionar expresión.
7. Ingresa su dirección IP en el campo provisto.
8. Guarda el filtro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa:

[Creación del filtro de dirección IP en Google Analytics](https://www.webregenesis.com/blog/how-to-easily-block-yourself-from-google-analytics/)

Comment: La alternativa del filtro desde Google Analytics es la más completa. Filtra cualquier dispositivo conectado desde esa IP (incluyendo celulares, tablets o cualquier otro dispoitivo móvil). Las extension de Chrome "Block Yourself from Analytics" no puede utilizarse desde Chrome Android.

Answer (score 1):

La forma que hago yo para aplicar los filtros de google es la siguiente:

Entra en **Administrar** ir a **Vista** da click en **Filtros** y seleccionar **Añadir Filtro** puedes configurar las opciones de la siguiente manera:[image: configuración de filtros en google Analytics]

Nombre del filtro siempre pongo la ip que tengo actual y las demás opciones las dejo así:

1. Excluir
2. tráfico de las direcciones IP
3. que son iguales a

Dirección IP debes de poner la IP actual, yo pongo nombre del filtro igual a la ip muchas veces el servicio eléctrico falla y al volver el servicio de electricidad cambia la ip, o de lo contrario deberías de contratar un IP estática.